# Jagged sides on ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have a simple ImageView slightly tilted to the left using the code below

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_on"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-1dp"
    android:contentDescription="@id/image_on"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:transformPivotX="48dp"
    android:transformPivotY="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/houseimage"
    android:antialias="true"
    android:rotation="-6"/>
```

When view on anything less than XXHDPI, the jagged sides could be clearly seen. It happens on higher resolution devices as well although not as clear.

The enlarged image look as below.

[image]

Anti-alias has been used, but doesn't seems to help. Any recommendation how to smoothen the image sides?

Comment: did you try programatically?

Comment: We have tried, and not seeing any thing different. If you have some idea, feel free to recommend. Using the above ImageView properties, you could replicate the issue easily on any XHDPI devices. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't find any direct way of doing, as apparently Android doesn't perform Anti-Alias across views border. To overcome this, we need to have a view that has transparent border (1px would suffice) to allow it to anti-alias with it's background.

Optionally, we could create a custom ImageView that programmatically add the 1 px transparent border. Refer to https://medium.com/@elye.project/smoothen-jagged-edges-of-rotated-image-view-1e56f6d8b5e9#.cfm8t71u8 for a solution for this issue.